# Dividing Particular Columns in Pandas dataframe by a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with columns a, b, c, and d. I would like to modify the dataframe so that columns c and d are divided by 100 but I can't figure out how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `df['columnC']  = df['columnC']/100`. Same for column D

Comment: so you want to divide everything in c/d by 100?

Comment: Yes I do. Also if there's a way to do it en mass instead of one by one (i have more than 2 columns but provided that in the example for simpicity's sake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
dff = pd.DataFrame({'a':[100,200,300], 'b':[400,500,600],'c':[700,800,900]})
display(dff)
dff.c = dff.c/100
dff
```

[image]

To do some complex calculations with other columns, we use `apply()` and pass a function to it such as ***lambda***:

```
dff.c = dff.apply(lambda row: (row.a + row.b)/2, axis =1)
```

The result is:

[image]